# Getting custom class from ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I am pretty new to Android, so please be gentle with me. I have a custom class that extends Object. It is called Word and through the course of the app, certain Words are added to an ArrayList. At the end of the activity, this ArrayList is passed via an Intent to another activity. In testing it, I just have it set up to take two Words and I know that they are both in the ArrayList before being passed to the new activity. When I get to the second activity, I have no problem accessing the ArrayList if I am only trying to get the 1st Word (ie [get(0)]). The problem is that when I also try to get (1), it throws an exception: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chase_crawford_69001.ltoj/chase_crawford_69001.ltoj.Finished}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to chase_crawford_69001.ltoj.Word"

Here is what I have:

```
public class Word extends Object implements Parcelable{
private String vocabWord;
private String definition;
private Boolean flagged = Boolean.FALSE;

public Word (String vocabWord, String definition) {
    this.vocabWord = vocabWord;
    this.definition = definition;}
public Word (String vocabWord){ //Used to make ten Language words so that all TextViews are full,
                                // but this will never be the correct answer.
    this.vocabWord = vocabWord;}

public String getVocabWord(){return vocabWord;}
public String getDefinition(){return definition;}
public Boolean getFlagged(){return flagged;}

public void setVocabWord(String vocabWord) {this.vocabWord = vocabWord;}
public void setDefinition(String definition) {this.definition = definition;}
public void setFlag(Boolean used){this.flagged = used;}

public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
    out.writeString(vocabWord);
    out.writeString(definition);
    out.writeValue(flagged);
  //  out.writeByte((byte) (flagged ? 1:0));//1 == TRUE, 0== FALSE
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Word> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Word>() {
    public Word createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Word(in);
    }

    public Word[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Word[size];
    }
};

private Word(Parcel in) {
    vocabWord = in.readString();
    definition = in.readString();
    flagged = in.readByte()!=0;//If not 0, flagged is true.
}
```

}
 from the 1st activity:

```
ArrayList<Word> missedWords = new ArrayList<>(); //this was instantiated at the beginning of the activity

else {
        view.setText("Try Again!");
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        if (!missedWords.contains(correctWord)) {
            missedWords.add(correctWord);}

 public void FinalMessage(View view) {

    Intent toFinished = new Intent(this, Finished.class);
    missedWordsBundle.putParcelableArrayList("missedWords", missedWords);
    toFinished.putExtra("missedWordsList", missedWordsBundle);
    startActivity(toFinished);
}
```

the second activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_finished);
    Intent words = getIntent();
    Bundle missedWordsBundle;
    ArrayList<Word> missedWords = new ArrayList();
    //missedWords = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("missedWords");
    missedWordsBundle = this.getIntent().getBundleExtra("missedWordsList");
    missedWords = missedWordsBundle.getParcelableArrayList("missedWords");


    MissedWords(missedWords);
}

public void MissedWords(ArrayList missedWords) {
    wordOne = (Word) missedWords.get(0);
    wordTwo = (Word) missedWords.get(1);

    String sWordOne = wordOne.getVocabWord();
    String sWordTwo = wordTwo.getVocabWord();
    TextView finished = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finished);
    TextView finishedOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finished1);
    String wrongList = sWordOne;// + " " +
    String wrongList1 =  sWordTwo;
    finished.setText(wrongList);
    finishedOne.setText(wrongList1);}
```

Would you please help me figure out why I am unable to get the second item from the ArrayList? I have been struggling with this for a couple weeks now, and am about to pull my hair out. I am sure that it is something simple that I am missing. Thank You!!!

Here is the complete error trace:

```
10-12 04:24:48.789 353-353/chase_crawford_69001.ltoj E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity        ComponentInfo{chase_crawford_69001.ltoj/chase_crawford_69001.ltoj.Finished}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to chase_crawford_69001.ltoj.Word
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2080)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to chase_crawford_69001.ltoj.Word
                                                                           at chase_crawford_69001.ltoj.Finished.missedWords(Finished.java:30)
                                                                           at chase_crawford_69001.ltoj.Finished.onCreate(Finished.java:25)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2044)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2105) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4795) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 

Line 30 is:  wordTwo = missedWords.get(1);
Line 25 is: missedWords(missedWords);
```

Comment: Hint: before accessing **any kind** of list/array ... you better check upfront if it contains the number of expected elements. And: you dont need to write "extends Object". That happens by default. So the real point here is: you might want to study the **basics** of Java a bit more, before adding the complexity of Android on top of that. You are like a person who just started to learn how to swim that now decides to swim the English Channel.

Comment: its better to use `out.writeByte((byte) (flagged ? 1:0))` instead `out.writeValue(flagged)`

Comment: Thank you, eventually I plan to add a new activity that it will take me to if there is anything in the array. If not it will just say that it is done. Like I said, I am pretty new to all of this so I take each step super-slow and make sure that it is working before I go to the next step. (I have been making sure to have two Words passed to the arraylist while testing every time.)

Comment: You always seem to define the list as `ArrayList<Word>` so the exception that you're getting doesn't really make sense.

Comment: The exception helps you to find an error. Cast exception basically tells you that you get a `String` in your array and your code is expecting a `Word`. So something else is calling your method with an incorrect array? Try putting some breakpoints in your code and debug at runtime. Also, please, please don't capitalise first letter in a method. Methods are started with a lower case, classes with a capital. That's what helps to differentiate a method from a class quickly, from a first glance at a code.

Comment: I have done some more testing: I changed all references throughout regarding this issue from Word to String. (the ArrayList, variables for Word in the second activity etc.) I also had it pass "test one" and "test two" (using the add() )in the "else" statement at the beginning of activity one instead of the word that was checked. (see below for more details on the general app functionality) When I did this, it did not throw an exception, but it put "test two" in both TextViews instead on "test one" and "test two."  Maybe this will give some more guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Parcel in  and Parcel out methods do not match in type. 
Parcel in has:

```
flagged = in.readByte()!=0;
```

while Parcel out has:

```
out.writeValue(flagged);
```

They need to both call the same type of method (Value or Byte)
In the end the code that worked was:

```
out.writeByte((byte) (flagged ? 1:0));//1 == TRUE, 0== FALSE
flagged = in.readByte()!=0;//If not 0, flagged is true.
```

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: I recommend you to use the parcelable plugin of Android Studio witch allow you to automatize parcelable creation. You will avoid this kinds of errors: http://corochann.com/fast-easy-parcelable-implementation-with-android-studio-parcelable-plugin-641.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to extends an Object if you create your own object model. So it will be like this

```
public class Word {
    private String vocabWord;
    private String definition;
    private Boolean flagged = Boolean.FALSE;

    public Word(String vocabWord, String definition) {
        this.vocabWord = vocabWord;
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public Word(String vocabWord) { //Used to make ten Language words so that all TextViews are full,
        // but this will never be the correct answer.
        this.vocabWord = vocabWord;
    }

    public String getVocabWord() {
        return vocabWord;
    }

    public String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }

    public Boolean getFlagged() {
        return flagged;
    }

    public void setVocabWord(String vocabWord) {
        this.vocabWord = vocabWord;
    }

    public void setDefinition(String definition) {
        this.definition = definition;
    }

    public void setFlag(Boolean used) {
        this.flagged = used;
    }
```

And then you can convert your ArrayList to String with Gson class like this

```
String stringList = new Gson().toJson(yourList);
```

Then put Extras to Intent

```
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY, stringList);
```

In second activity you can get your stringList and convert then it again to ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Word> list = new Gson().fromJson(br, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Word>>(){}.getType());
```

Note that it is bad practice and bad for performance, but is simply and short code

Comment: But he is already implementing parcelable and he doesn't need to do anything with Gson.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding using Gson for passing data between activities. You shouldn't really do any Gson parsing on a main thread as it can take time to parse large objects

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as Hank Moody just said you don't need to extends from Object. Maybe your error could be in the method MissedWords (you should rename it as missedWords in order to follow Java code style) because your aren't defining the type of the arraylist and you need to casting. If you refactor the method like this you won't need the casting anymore:

```
public void missedWords(ArrayList<Word> missedWords) {
    Word wordOne = missedWords.get(0);
    Word wordTwo = missedWords.get(1);
```

Also you need to know if there is a second word in missedWords (you couldn't have or even you could have none of them). It's difficult to say if we don't know what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I have made the changes you recommended and get the same exception. More detail: This program takes twenty random Words (vocab words from my daughter's school) and displays one at a time. It also displays nine distractor words at the same time. The definition for the correct word is displayed and she selects the word from among the ten options that matches the definition to display. If correct, it moves to the next Word question. If wrong, it tells her to try again, and adds that word to the missedWords ArrayList. I know that both words are in the ArrayList before the intent by testing...

Comment: ...and if I only try to display one Word (ie "//" all of the lines regarding the second word) it works fine. I only get this exception when there are two wrong words in the list and I try to display both of them with the above code.

Comment: Well, maybe we need more information. Could you please edit your question and add the complete error trace?

Comment: @ChaseC I don't think it is possible for the code that you're posted to produce the exception that you've mentioned. Try to change the `MissedWords` method signature to `MissedWords(ArrayList<Word> missedWords)` to see if it is called from some other part of your code with a list that isn't of type `Word`.

Comment: ok, i don't understand yet what's happening here. Please, add to your question more code about correctWord. It's very strange what is happening because you cannot put a string inside an ArrayList<Word>. If you try to do that the code couldn't compile.

Comment: Also, put a break point where you extract the ParcelableArrayList and tell us what is exactly extracting, maybe is not an ArrayList<Word> and you need to casting.